# Avoid putting "global" in every single function

Tags: python, global-variables

Python is supposed to be fun, simple and easy to learn.

Instead, it's been a huge pain.

I've discovered that all the errors I'm getting are related to me not declaring each variable global in each function.

So for my toy program of `dressUp`, I have to write:

```
hatColor = ""
shirtColor = ""
pantsColor = ""

    def pickWardrobe(hat, shirt, pants):
         global hatColor
         global shirtColor
         global pantsColor
         ...
```

This gets really annoying when I have 20 functions, and each one needs to have 20 global declarations at the beginning.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks!

**ADDED**

I am getting tons of `UnboundLocalError - local variable X referenced before assignment.

Why am I doing this? Because I need to write a `py` file that can do some calculations for me. I don't want it all in the same function, or it gets messy and I can't reuse code. But if I split the work among a few functions, I have to declare these annoying globals over and over.

Comment: why are you doing that? what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Definitely need more information. What errors are you getting? Where are you getting the errors? What troubleshooting steps have you taken so far?

Comment: It seems that you've learned an antipattern from another language or from previous experience, and now try to shoehorn it into Python. You might want to study articles or existing Python code to see what kind of pattern works best with Python.

Comment: Imray: any time you want to use `global` in Python, find a way to do it WITHOUT global instead. Only in VERY rare instances is `global` actually a necessary evil (kind of like using `eval`)

Answer (score 1):

## Classes versus global variables

`global` is common to all

class is a template for an object, representing something, here it could be person dressed up somehow.

Class might have class properties, these are not so commonly used, as they are shared by all instances (sort of "global for classes).

Classes start living as soon as you instantiate them, it means, the pattern defined by class definition is realized in form of unique object.

Such an object, called instance, might have it's own properties, which are not shared with other instances.

I am sometime thinking about a class as of a can - class definition means "can is something you can put thing into" and instance is real tangible can, which has a name of it and in Python I put property values into it, which are bound to the name of given can holder.

## DressUp class with real instance properties

Properties in "holmeswatson" solution are bound to class definition. You would run into problems if you would use multiple instances of DressUp, they would be sharing the properties over class definition.

It is better and safer to use it as instance variables, which are over `self` bound to instance of the class, not to class definition.

Modified code:

```
class DressUp:

    def __init__(self, name, hatColor="", shirtColor=""):
        self.name = name
        self.hatColor = hatColor
        self.shirtColor = shirtColor

    def pickWardrobe(self,hat, shirt):
        self.hatColor = hat
        self.shirtColor = shirt

    def __repr__(self):
        name = self.name
        hatColor = self.hatColor
        shirtColor = self.shirtColor

        templ = "<Person:{name}: hat:{hatColor}, shirt:{shirtColor}>"
        return templ.format(name=name, hatColor=hatColor, shirtColor=shirtColor)


tom = DressUp("Tom")

tom.pickWardrobe("red","yellow")
print "tom's hat is", tom.hatColor
print "simple print:", tom
print "__repr__ call:", tom.__repr__()

jane = DressUp("Jane")

jane.pickWardrobe("pink","pink")
print "jane's hat is", jane.hatColor
print "simple print:", jane
print "__repr__ call:", jane.__repr__()
```

The `__repr__` method is used at the moment, you call `print tom` or `print jane`.

It is used here to show, how to instance method can get access to instance properties.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way around it?  Yes, there are several.  If you're using global variables on a regular basis, you're making a mistake in your design.

One common pattern when you have many functions that will operate on the same, related data is to create a class and then declare instances of that class.  Each instance has its own set of data and methods, and the methods within that instance can operate on the data within that instance.

This is called object oriented programming, it is a common and basic paradigm in modern programming.

Several respondents have sketched out what a class might look like in your case but I don't think you've given enough information (which would include the method signatures of the other functions) to actually write out what you need.  If you post more information you might get some better examples.

Answer (score -1):

If it is appropriate, you could use classes.

```
class DressUp:

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

  def pickWardrobe(self,hat, shirt, pants):
    self.hatColor = hat
    self.shirtColor = shirt
    self.pantsColor = pants


 obj1 = DressUp("Tom")

 obj1.pickWardrobe("red","yellow","blue")
 print obj1.hatColor
```

Have a look:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: Why do you have both class and instance variables with the same names, isn't that confusing?  You never use the class variables for anything.  And why initialize them to empty strings instead of None?

Comment: I printed out one of the class vars. I don't know what the user wants to do with the vars. simply an illustration

Comment: No, you've printed the instance variable from `obj1`.  The class variables are never used.  Add the statement `print obj1.__class__.hatColor` at the end of your program to see the value (an empty string) held in the class variable.

Comment: @holmeswatson Using class variables as alternative to `global` is simply bad, you still have values globally shared across all instances, despite the small difference in accessing them (either by `hatColor` or by `DressUp.hatColor`.